# how to stop on click event from multiplying its effect every time i use it

Tags: javascript

i have 8 pictures and want to make a slider in an external div by using them everything seems to work fine after open the first picture and use the slider , then after closing the slider div and open it again the rightarrow and leftarrow on click seems to work twice so it slides two pictures at one click , and if i close the div again and reopen it the right and left arrows will slide 3 pictures and so on here is the code

```
currentpic = 1;

allzoomicons.forEach((icon , index) => {

    icon.onclick = function() {
         mainContainer.classList.add("overlay");
         rightarrow.style.setProperty("display" , "block");
         leftarrow.style.setProperty("display" , "block");
         let picdiv = document.createElement("div");
         picdiv.className = "picdiv";
         document.body.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', picdiv);
         closeicondiv.style.setProperty("display" , "block");
         picdiv.appendChild(closeicondiv);
         picarray[currentpic - 1].classList.add("active")
         picdiv.appendChild(picarray[currentpic - 1]);
         rightarrow.addEventListener("click" , r =>{
         picarray[currentpic - 1].classList.remove("active");
         picarray[currentpic].classList.add("active");
         picdiv.appendChild(picarray[currentpic]);
         currentpic++;
         if(currentpic === 8){
         rightarrow.classList.add("stopping");
         }
         if(currentpic === 2){
            leftarrow.classList.remove("stopping");
          }
     })
          leftarrow.addEventListener("click" , l =>{
          currentpic--;
          picarray[currentpic].classList.remove("active");
          picarray[currentpic - 1].classList.add("active");
          picdiv.appendChild(picarray[currentpic]);
                    
          if(currentpic === 1){
          leftarrow.classList.add("stopping");
          }if(currentpic == 7){
          rightarrow.classList.remove("stopping");
          }
        })
       // close mark click
          closeicondiv.onclick = function(){
          picdiv.remove();
          rightarrow.style.setProperty("display" , "none");
          leftarrow.style.setProperty("display" , "none");
          mainContainer.classList.remove("overlay");
          closeicondiv.remove();
          console.log(`close ${currentpic}`);
          currentpic = 1;
          picarray.forEach(arr =>{
          arr.classList.remove("active")
        })
       }
      }
    })
```

Comment: @IT goldman    i applied an editor , still couldnt know which brackets are causing the problem

Comment: if you have this happen, you're calling your javascript that attaches events each time you go to that view.  We don't see how you're calling this code, but it needs to just run once in document ready.  Javascript doesn't care how many event handlers are on a div.  It will just keep adding them.

Answer (score 0):

See what happens you keep attaching the click event every time you click.
That was because you had some issues with your `{` and `(`. Indent your code using an editor to catch those.

```
currentpic = 1;

allzoomicons.forEach((icon, index) => {

    icon.onclick = function () {
        mainContainer.classList.add("overlay");
        rightarrow.style.setProperty("display", "block");
        leftarrow.style.setProperty("display", "block");
        let picdiv = document.createElement("div");
        picdiv.className = "picdiv";
        document.body.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', picdiv);
        closeicondiv.style.setProperty("display", "block");
        picdiv.appendChild(closeicondiv);
        picarray[currentpic - 1].classList.add("active")
        picdiv.appendChild(picarray[currentpic - 1]);
        rightarrow.addEventListener("click", r => {
            picarray[currentpic - 1].classList.remove("active");
            picarray[currentpic].classList.add("active");
            picdiv.appendChild(picarray[currentpic]);
            currentpic++;
            if (currentpic === 8) {
                rightarrow.classList.add("stopping");
            }
            if (currentpic === 2) {
                leftarrow.classList.remove("stopping");
            }
        })
    }

    leftarrow.addEventListener("click", l => {
        currentpic--;
        picarray[currentpic].classList.remove("active");
        picarray[currentpic - 1].classList.add("active");
        picdiv.appendChild(picarray[currentpic]);

        if (currentpic === 1) {
            leftarrow.classList.add("stopping");
        }
        if (currentpic == 7) {
            rightarrow.classList.remove("stopping");
        }
    })
    
    // close mark click
    closeicondiv.onclick = function () {
        picdiv.remove();
        rightarrow.style.setProperty("display", "none");
        leftarrow.style.setProperty("display", "none");
        mainContainer.classList.remove("overlay");
        closeicondiv.remove();
        console.log(`close ${currentpic}`);
        currentpic = 1;
        picarray.forEach(arr => {
            arr.classList.remove("active")
        })
    }
})
```